# How do I add a view controller to the scroll view but only instantiate the view controller when the scroll view is showing that vc?

Tags: ios, swift

I added two view controllers to my scroll view, and have animations on both view controllers, but those animations should only be called when the vc is showing. Instead both animations are being executed when the first vc is showing.

```
func setUpScrollView() {

        for i in 0..<2 {
            let vc = NewViewController()
            self.addChildViewController(vc)
            scrollView.addSubview(vc.view)
            vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

            var frame: CGRect = vc.view.frame
            frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            vc.view.frame = frame

            self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(2), height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        }
    }
```

NewViewController

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated) 
         print("calling animation") //this is called twice immediatley after for loop, but only shows one vc. 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIScrollView` doesn't manage content loading the way a `UITableView` does, so whatever you put in the scroll view's content area will fire its `viewDidAppear` immediately whether it is in the visible area or not.

To decide when to start your animation, you're going to have to manually keep track of what is actually visible in the scroll view's content area:

Assign a `UIScrollViewDelegate` and do the check in its `scrollViewDidScroll()`, which is called every frame that the scrollView is scrolling.

You can use `scrollView.contentOffset` and `scrollView.bounds` along with the size and coordinates of the subview you're interested in to determine visibility, then trigger your animation when it first becomes visible.